# C# - Listbox Key/value pair

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, user-interface

I have a Dictionary, which contains data like so:

```
key     Value
UK01    Building 1
UK02    Building 2
```

I have a textbox in which data is populated like this:

```
foreach (var building in dictionary)
{
    listbox1.Items.Add(building.Value);
}
```

This then displays `Building 1 Building 2, ...`

Problem:

What I want to do is so that when the `SelectionChanged` is triggered, I can access the Key/Value for the option that has been selected and store these as variables which I can use later on. Currently I can only get the item selected, i.e "Building 1" or I can get the `SelectedInded`but this only gives me: 1, 2, .. And I understand why.

Is it therefore possible (elegantly) so that the key/value can be accessed without displaying the key? I have tried to use a class:

```
 public class Test
 {
    public ID { get; set; }
    public value { get; set; }

 }
```

But this did not work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `DataTemplate` in your `ListBox` to ensure the listbox knows how to render it's content. Assuming you follow your class based approach as above:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding value}">
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This creates a `DataTemplate` for each item you have added to the `ListBox` which contains a text block which is bound to a property on the items added

Read up on binding - it is one of the most powerful things in WPF/WP7/Silverlight and probably one of the most extensive implementations of binding out there

http://www.mono-software.com/blog/post/Mono/166/Data-binding-in-Windows-Phone-7-application/

Edit:

Though I'm pretty sure the default template for ListBox is just to call 'ToString()' on each item... so it should be working anyway!

Oh and consider making the members auto-properties instead of fields:

```
public string ID { get; set; }
```

Edit:

Ok I'm not great with Linq but since the query should return an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` as far as I can see, you can just enumerate it and build your objects off it e.g.

```
var myList = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
foreach(var kvp in dict) 
{
    myList.Add(new MyClass(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)); 
    // Or myList.Add(new MyClass() { ID = kvp.Key, Value = kvp.Value }); depending on your constructor
}
```

Having said this, there no reason why you can't just point to the key/value of the dictionary items (`KeyValuePair<string, string>` is just a reference type like anything else)

This:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}">
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Should give you

```
{Key}
{Value}
{Key}
{Value}
{Key}
{Value}
```

In your listbox

Assuming you don't need any additional functionality from the result items `KeyValuePair` should suffice. Creating a class just to show some values may be overkill since you are already 99% of the way there.

You might want to look at some MVVM patterns and maybe get into looking at an MVVM framework (I'm biased because I use it all the time but Caliburn.Micro is really easy to get started with and supports WP7).

Your code wouldn't be any more complex, but certain things would be wired up for you and it would give you more feedback as to where you are going wrong with bindings etc (some bindings are hard to figure out especially when popups/contextmenus are involved)

If you are serious about developing for XAML based technologies, they go hand in hand with the MVVM pattern, and a framework just makes things a cinch

If you are interested there's an easy to follow tut here:

https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Basic%20Configuration%2c%20Actions%20and%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation

Another variation on the same tut with a bit more info is here:

http://buksbaum.us/2010/08/01/caliburn-micro-hello-world/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I have read the blog post you gave me, however, I read the data in differently. Please could you look at where I am going wrong, since I don't actually affect "ID" in class "Test" ... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So I fixed the Binding errors and they WORK! Well, it displays each of the items. BUT here is what I am confused about. When the item changes, I need to update 2 variables with the values (stored in the dictionary).. e.g. "BL1  Building 1" would be stored as "var id = BL1" var building = "Building 1" but how would I access the members? Because I only have listbox1.selectedIndex -> listbox1.selectedItem which do not contain these data.. Any ideas? At a loss now

Comment: That's because `SelectedItem` now contains the actual selected item - which is a `KeyValuePair<string, string>`. The item contains your values, but since `SelectedItem` is `object` (so that the combo can hold any type) your code-behind won't know what actual type the reference is. You can cast `SelectedItem` to the type you are expecting: `var item = (KeyValuePair<string,string>)someCombo.SelectedItem` and then `item.Key` be the id and `item.Value` will be the building name. Bear in mind, if you cast something to a type which is incompatible you will get an `InvalidCastException`

Comment: Assuming you are not familiar with typecasting you might want to read up: http://www.dotnetperls.com/cast seems like a good start

Comment: Sorry to be a pain. But 'var item = (KeyValuePair<string,string>)someCombo.SelectedItem' even returns a invalid cast type, but I am storing them as <string, string> any ideas? I've tried <int, string> and <char, string>

Comment: Just put a breakpoint on your code and watch the `SelectedItem` property before the cast executes (you can put the breakpoint on the same line as the cast) - remember that you might have an empty item in there or something of that nature. Right click on the `SelectedItem` in code and choose 'Add Watch' or type `someCombo.SelectedItem` into the 'Watch' column in the watch window. You should see the value - it should be `KeyValuePair<string,string>` as far as I can tell from your code, but it may just be null (no item selected). Worst case, can you post your entire code in the question!

Comment: Hey, I've updated my original post with the new code. Thank you for this, I'm new to this kind of development and /style/ so your help is greatly appreciated. I Did the watch, however, it just returned as a 'Text' and a 'null' object.

Comment: I see what you've done - you are using a hybridisation of the two approaches - basically you've created a class to wrap the items (`Test` class) so items in the list will be of type `Test`. You can either cast to `Test` e.g. `var item = (Test)someCombo.SelectedItem` or remove the code which creates `myList` and instead just assign `dict` to the `ItemsSource` of the combobox, update your template to use Key/Value instead of ID/Value and use the cast you already have

Comment: Thank you so much. For taking time out to help me and having the patience :) It's fixed now and I can carry on. Once again, thank you!

Comment: No problemo! You want to probably have a read up on the `object` type, casting, inheritance etc etc general c# stuff - now I've got a washing machine hose clip to try and remove :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23586/discussion-between-phorce-and-charleh)

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to override the `ToString` function in your `Test` class and it should work as you want it to

like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated my original post, but I don't understand what I have to write so the contents are displayed onto "listbox1" could you please take a look? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know WPF and somewhat it should be similar. 
There you can bind a control to a collection with something called **data binding**.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/07/25/windows-phone-7-binding-data-to-listbox-through-code.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I know this sounds a bit stupid, but, do you think this solution would work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885271/how-to-display-a-dictionary-in-a-listbox (accepted answer)